# Batch: List recent files and their modification date

Tags: batch, date-modified

**If you want a simple explanation of what I want instead of the full context just read what is in bold.** 
I'm working on a projects that replicates an old telnet server, running off of batch code. I need to create the *who* command, a command that would list recent users and how long ago they issued a command. I have it set up so that every time a user runs a "command" it echos a variable into a file in a folder called `online` with the file name set to their username. Now, to have the who command work I need to be able to process how long ago the command was issued. That being said, I really only want it to show users that issued a command in the last five minutes.
 So basically what I need is to do is the following: 
**1] I need to be able to delete files from a directory that are older than five minutes old.** 
 **2] I need to be able to get how long ago a file** (specifically those remaining files) **was modified in a format like: `This file was modified 5 Minutes and 32 Seconds ago.` if the file was only modified 5 seconds ago it would preferably be formatted `This file was modified 5 seconds ago`.** And the file having been created under a second ago cant crash it. I don't care if it says `created 0 seconds ago` but it cant say `created (blank) seconds ago`.

Because of how it is set up it does *not* have to be locale dependent. Here is an example of what `%time%` and `%date%` are set to on my machine: `Sat 03/23/2019, 17:49:47.98`

I originally had it set so that it would echo the date and time with no colons or slashes into those files, but it has not been dependable for mathematical calculations.

**how would I go about doing this?**

here's what I had so far:

(excerpt from entire script)

```batch
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set TME=%time::=%
set TME=%TME: =%
Set Compare=%date:~7,2%%TME:.=%
echo.
echo Recent Users:
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b ..\Online') do (
    for /f "usebackq" %%i in ("..\Online\%%A") do (
        set /a Value=%Compare% - %%i
        if !Value! LSS 90000 (
            if !value! LEQ 99 (
                echo %%A   !Value! ms ago
            ) ELSE (
                if !value! GTR 9999 (
                    echo %%A   !Value:~0,-4! minutes !Value:~1,-2! seconds ago.
                ) ELSE (
                    echo %%A   !Value:~0,-2! seconds ago.
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
echo.
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Of course I know that. In what way am I asking for a script?

Comment: This is part of a Whois server script. The rest of the script does not alter the function of this portion so I did not ask for it. I am asking for a *technique to get my requirements done.*

Comment: @DavidPostill I edited it to add in what I have so far. I didn't have access to it before.

Comment: So where are you stuck in your code? Where is it failing? What output is it producing? What is wrong with the output?. It's **your** code. You need to be explicit about what is wrong. Please [edit] the question.

Comment: While calculating datetime/-differences in batch is extremely tedious (and time consuming) , it **IS**  possible, see [batchfunctionlibrary/date-and-time-functions](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/batchfunctionlibrary/#date-and-time-functions). But I suggest to use PowerShell instead (evtentually invoked from batch).

Comment: I’ll look into powershell, thanks. And I can get the error for you soon. Don’t remember off the top of my head.